# Path diagram plot: latent growth curve model customisation

Tags: r, plot, r-lavaan, sem, semplot

I have created a latent growth curve model in lavaan and created a path diagram to represent this. However, on the path diagram plot I would like to...

1. remove the intercepts for specific vairables; the predictor variable (x1) and the indicator variables (T0/Year0, T1/Year1, T2/Year2 and T3/Year3).
2. include confidence intervals with the estimates on the plot

I cannot see how to do this using the existing functions - is there a work around?

Thanks in advance!

```
# Load relevant packages
library(lavaan) #for SEM LGCM
library(semTools) # for fit indices 
library(semPlot) # for path diagrams
library(semptools) # for path diagrams
library(tidyverse) # pipelines, exploring and visualizing data

# model
model_fit <- ' 
# intercept with fixed coefficients
  i =~ 1*T0 + 1*T1 + 1*T2 + 1*T3
# slope with fixed coefficients
  s =~ 0*T0 + 1*T1 + 2*T2 + 3*T3

# time invariant covaraites
 # regression of time-invariant covariates on intercept and slope factors
  i ~  x1 + covar1 + covar2 + covar3
  s ~ x1 + covar1 + covar2 + covar3
'

fit <- growth(model_fit, data=LGCM_data, missing="fiml", estimator = "MLR")
summary(fit,fit.measures=TRUE, ci=TRUE)


# Plot   
lgcm_no_covs <- semptools::drop_nodes(
                 object = semPlotModel(fit),
                 nodes = c("covar1", "covar2", "covar3")) 

lgcm_no_covs <- semPaths(lgcm_no_covs, whatLabels = "est",
                    label.norm = "PAL \nBaseline",
                    edge.label.cex = 1.0, label.cex = 2.0,
                    edge.color = "black", edge.label.color = "black",
                    height = 20, width = 12,
                    residuals = FALSE,
                    DoNotPlot= TRUE)  

my_label_list <- list(list(node = "i", to = "Intercept"),
                     list(node = "s", to = "Slope"),
                     list(node = "x1", to = "Predictor"),
                     list(node = "T0", to = "Baseline"),
                     list(node = "T1", to = "Year 1"),
                     list(node = "T2", to = "Year 2"),
                     list(node = "T3", to = "Year 3")
                     )

lgcm_no_covs <- change_node_label(lgcm_no_covs, my_label_list)

plot(lgcm_no_covs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not supported to only draw some intercepts, nor is it supported to draw confidence intervals.